# wait for task complete in unit test

Tags: .net, wpf, unit-testing, dispatcher

I have simple window with Button and TextBox named *SimpleText*

```
/// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TestMe();

        }

        public Task TestMe()
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 11000; i++)
                {
                    var text = i;
                    SimpleText.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => SimpleText.Text = text.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

When I click on button program exectute *ButtonClicked*
Then I decide to test this code

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            Assert.IsNotNull(mainWindow);


            var task =  mainWindow.TestMe();
            DispatcherUtil.DoEvents();

            Assert.AreEqual(mainWindow.SimpleText.Text, "11000");
        }
```

*DispatcherUtil* is helper class. Help me do events from dispatcher queue

```
public static class DispatcherUtil
    {
        [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
        public static void DoEvents()
        {
            var frame = new DispatcherFrame();
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
            Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
        }

        private static object ExitFrame(object frame)
        {
            ((DispatcherFrame)frame).Continue = false;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My test falling with textbox value "34".  Sometimes test falls with value "56". Therefore I need to wait all queue completed. How can I do this?

If I wait by task.Wait() my test is running without ending and never completed

Answer (score 0):

OK I know what is happening here: your test method and `SimpleText.Dispatcher` run on the same thread what that means is that if you call `SimpleText.Dispatcher.Invoke` and then `task.Wait()` you have a classic deadlock:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    Assert.IsNotNull(mainWindow);

    var task =  mainWindow.TestMe();
    DispatcherUtil.DoEvents(); // synchronously invokes onto this thread
    task.Wait(); // blocks this thread so DoEvents is blocked (I've added this).

    Assert.AreEqual(mainWindow.SimpleText.Text, "11000");
}
```

If you now change the `Invoke` to `BeginInvoke` the call is no longer synchronous and it all works.

```
public Task TestMe()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 11000; i++)
        {
            var text = i;
            SimpleText.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( 
                // this is now asynchronous so non-blocking
                () => SimpleText.Text = 
                         text.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is test example. In real project I must use Invoke, because I get some result from Invoke action that necassary for further computations

Comment: OK, but can you see why you can't run your test with `Invoke`? The task starts on some other thread and then requires synchronous access to the original thread but it cannot get it because you are in the middle of a method.